# The name 'DateFormat' isn't a class. Try correcting the name to match an existing class

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

i have a dateTime like this `2022-08-27T12:03:03.484Z` , i try to create a methode to remove the character T and Z :

**My methode**

```
String ConverTime(String varia) {
    DateTime parseDate =
        new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(varia);
    var inputDate = DateTime.parse(parseDate.toString());
    var outputFormat = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a');
    var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
    return outputDate;
  }
```

so i got this error:

```
    The name 'DateFormat' isn't a class.
Try correcting the name to match an existing class.dartcreation_with_non_type
```

how can i solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `DateFormat` class, you need to import `intl` package.

Open the `pubspec.yaml` file and add these line below `dependencies` section:

```
intl: ^0.17.0
```

Example:

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.17.0
```

`0.17.0` is the current version.

You can find more information at https://pub.dev/packages/intl